# Thread Pool Management in WSO2 Micro Integrator: Exploring Sequence Handling in Request-Response Flows

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

How does WSO2 Micro Integrator manage thread pools? I also have a question regarding thread usage in sequences – specifically, whether the same thread pool is utilized for both the in-sequence and out-sequence. In a scenario where an HTTP message is received, a request is sent to an external REST API, and the response is received from the client, I'm curious to know if the entire flow operates using the same thread or not.

Answer (score 0):

By default the "non-blocking" mode is being used, this means request (inSequence) and response (outSequence) run in a separate thread. After `<send>` or `<call>` the current thread is closed.

You can enable Blocking Mode in the `<call>` mediator to stay in the same thread by enabling

`blocking=true` like this:

```
<call blocking="true">
```

See here the documentation of the `<call>` Mediator: https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/call-mediator/